# SSRS Report From SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: 2013, list, reporting-services

I've created a SSRS report from a SharePoint list. The list has about 65000 records. When I ran this report, all SharePoint web applications and all sites stuck on loading. After report finished executing all sites turn to normal. How can I solve this problem? Is this an infrastructure problem at our farm or something related with SharePoint? Any ideas?

P.S: I'm using SharePoint 2013 with 2 FE, 1 AP and 1 DB server.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like you have issues with a table lock. Table locks happen if you retrieve to many items from a sharepoint list. This is usually prevented by the list throttling feature.

Do you have turned that feature off since you need to bypass it for that list?

SQL will promote row locks to a table lock at 5000 items. When this happens everyone (in that database) needs to wait till the table lock is done.

You can lessen your pain by moving your site into its own SQL-DB, which it should not share with any other site collection. The best option of course is to only retrieve fewer records ;)

(edit) : Fixed an error in the reply

Comment: also i also would recommend using PowerPivot with Excel Services instead of SharePoint list for that many amount of items if possible, even BDCS has a 20,000 limit for data retrival